# Can there always exist a series that converges to a real number?

Tags: real-analysis

Say I have a real number $x$. Can I find a sequence $(a_i)$ such that $\sum {a_i} = x, a_i \in \mathbb{N}$. Proof? But if not, what's the best I can have?

Edit: A series with entries from $\mathbb{N}$, just to be clear.

Comment: How can a sequence of natural numbers converge to anything other than a natural number?  Did you mean rational number?

Comment: @lulu I've edited my question. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: do you mean a sequence or a series?

Comment: Well, an infinite series with natural numbers as entries can't converge at all (unless all terms vanish after a point).

Comment: take $a_0 = x$ and $a_i = 0 \forall i \neq 0$

Comment: @Börge Terms are supposed to be elements of $\Bbb N$.

Comment: What if entries are in $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: than you can  only get natural x .....

Comment: You can find such a sequence if and only if $x\in \mathbb{N}$. Unless you belong to "the church of $0 \notin \mathbb{N}$", in which case you can never find such a sequence. For $a_i \in \mathbb{Z}$, you can find such a sequence if and only if $x\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Given that all the $a_i$ are integers: If infinitely many $a_i \neq 0$, can $\sum a_i$ converge? If only finitely many $a_i \neq 0$ then what can you say about the sum? Can it be irrational?

Comment: no it can't converge.... do you know the Cauchy -Criteria?

Comment: How would you get, say, $\frac12$? (Note that $1-1+1-1+\dotsb$ does _not_ converge.)

Comment: at least not in the standard way....

Comment: @DanielFischer I'm a member of that church, hah. I never thought $0$ was natural.

Comment: you could get 1/2 by abel-summability i think....

Comment: @zhw. That's why god invented the symbols $\mathbb{N}^+, \mathbb{N}_{>0}$.

Comment: @Börge Yes, with Abel summation you can get _any_ real even if the terms are all in $\{-1,1\}$. But that's not actual convergence.

Comment: @zhw. But $0$ is the most natural of all numbers. When we were born, we had $0$ money, $0$ knowledge of mathematics and science, $0$ friends …

Comment: @DanielFischer ... and we were 0 years old.

Comment: @DanielFischer $0$ escaped even the great Greek mathematicians of antiquity. They didn't even have a name for it.

Comment: @BrianO In many cultures they start at $1$, since you're "in your _first_ year."

Comment: @zhw. But they didn't consider $1$ a number either. If you go Greek, you have to say $\mathbb{N} = \{2,3,4,5,\dotsc\}$.

Comment: Whaaaat${}{}{}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you meant a sequence of **rational** numbers.  Yes, it is true that, given any real number, x, there exist a sequence of rational numbers (in fact, an infinite number of such sequences) that converges to x.  Indeed, one can **define** the real numbers as an "equivalence classes" of Cauchy sequences (or increasing sequences with upper bound or decreasing sequences with lower bound) where two sequences $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$ are "equivalent if and only if the sequence $\{a_n- b_n\}$ converges to 0.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is ***no***.

Formally the necessary condition of convergence of $\sum a_n$ is that $$\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=0$$
Then, for large $n$, $a_n$ must be equal to $0$, because if we take $\varepsilon<1$ then there exists only one integer that belongs to $(-\varepsilon;\varepsilon)$. Since sum of finite number of natural numbers is always a natural number,

$$\sum a_n\in\mathbb{N}$$

Same situation with integers.